# parsing json through jquery, but html coming undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to read json through jquery. But i am getting undefined in my html.

Below is the html jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                 $.getJSON('Json.json',function(data){
                    $('#output').empty();
                        $.each(data.general, function(entry){
                    var html = '<div class="general">';                    
                    html += '<span class="logo">' + entry['logo'] + '</span>';
                    html += '<span class="name">' + entry['name'] + '</span>';
                    html += '</div>';                                                       
                    $('#output').append(html);
                });                        
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Below is my JSON:

```
"general":{
      "logo":"assets/images/logo.png",
      "name" : "Company Name"
   }
```

JSON is validated through JSLint. Please tell me where i am going wrong.

Thanks!

i updated my code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                 $.getJSON('Json.json',function(data){
                    $('#output').empty();                       
                    var html = '<div class="general">';                    
                    html += '<h3>' + data.general.logo+ '</h3>';
                    html += '<div class="name">' + data.general.name+ '</div>';
                    html += '</div>';  
                    html +='<div class="navigation" >';                                                 
                    $('#output').append(html);                                     
            });
            return false;
        });
```

it is working now!!

Comment: try debugging your values in $.each loop

Comment: Could you edit your post and put the full error message? :)

Answer (score 0):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/Ds3xT/)

So the only thing that should be inside your each loop is the step that you want to repeat for every entry in the map; initializing the `html` variable should not be done there. Then, to iterate over entries in the associative array, the parameters to the callback function are `key` and `value`, and it's obvious what these correspond to based on the variable names I've used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('Json.json',function(data){
        $('#output').empty();

        var html = '<div class="general">'; 
        $.each(data.general, function(key, val){
            html += '<span class="'+key+'">' + val + '</span>';
        });
        html += '</div>';                                                 
        $('#output').append(html);
    });
    //return false; Not sure why you had this...you don't need it
});
```